# Using Jquery AutoComplete with dictionary list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dictionary list of about 58040 words and i don't think jquery auto complete can handle that many words as the browser hangs.

The list is

```
words = ['axxx','bxxx','cxxx', an so on];

$(".CreateAddKeyWords input").autocomplete({ source: words });
```

Am i doing something wrong

Is there another free tool that i can use

### Edit

i am using .net and i have retrieved the data fro the database and can loop through the data server side, but how do you send the data back, if json format how should the format look like?

Comment: 58040 words? That sure adds a few bytes to the page's size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there another free tool that i can use

Yes, instead of hardcoding 58040 words in your HTML or javascript file you could load them from a [remote datasource](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) using AJAX. Basically you will have a server side script which when queries with the current user input will prefilter the result and send it to the client to display suggestions.

Comment: @redoc01, it could be any server side script that can return the expected JSON format. And if not you could still register a custom parser that will map the server response. Read the documentation for examples.

Comment: Darin's answer is good, I changed my comment to an answer below as it may also be an issue for you.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, i am using .net and i have retrieved the data fro the database and can loop through the data server side, but how do you send the data back, if json format how should the format look like?

Comment: @redoc01, like this `[ { "id": "1", "label": "word 1", "value": "word 1" }, { "id": "2", "label": "word 2", "value": "word 2" }, { "id": "3", "label": "word 3", "value": "word 3" } ]`. Basically you need to return a JSON array of objects where each object has an `id`, `label` and `value` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a minimum length of user entry before searching (so it isn't querying with 1 or 2 characters).

`$(".CreateAddKeyWords input").autocomplete({ source: words, minLength: 3 });`

It's possible the browser is hanging because it is trying to search on the very first character which is not very useful.  ~58k entries is not a large dataset by most regards, especially when you narrow it by 2-3 character contents requirements.

Answer (score 0):

That's just way too much data to have it load in your webpage.  Limit it to 2 letters.

1) set the autocomplete min length to at least 2

2) Create a webpage that returns JSON data - http://mydomain.com/words.php?q={letters}
You can have the filter sort be 'begins with' before 'contains'; or any variation you prefer.

Use that page as your remote data source.  With the min length set, autocomplete knows when to  query for new data.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was an interesting problem, and hacked up a backend service that solves auto-completion.

My code is at https://github.com/badgerman/fastcgi/ (look for complete.c), and the quick and dirty javascript proof of concept from that repository is currently at http://enno.kn-bremen.de/prefix.html (no guarantees that it will stay up for very long, since this is running on the Raspberry Pi in my home).